# How to select the second element with same attribute ID in an XPATH?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Imagine an HTML snippet as follows:

```
<div>
    <div class="content">test1</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="content">test2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="content">test3</div>
</div>
```

and the xpath I'm using is `//div[@class='content']`

Now, I want to refer to the Second div element. What should I add to my xpath? 
TIA.

Comment: //div[@class='content'][2]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two solutions have been proposed so far, but none of them selects anything from the HTML snippet you show in the question. When simply wrapping it in a root element:

```
<root>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test1</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test2</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test3</div>
 </div>
</root>
```

Both `//div[@class='content'][2]` and `//div[2][@class='content']` select nothing from that document. They both assume that the second predicate (between `[` and `]`) is applied to an intermediate result sequence, but the second predicate is also applied to the nodes of the initial document tree. To select a subset of an "intermediate" result, use parentheses around the first part:

```
(//div[@class='content'])[2]
```

and the single result will be

```
<div class="content">test2</div>
```

---

**More details**

`//div[@class='content'][2]` means:

> Select all elements called `div` from anywhere in the document, but only the ones that have a `class` attribute whose value is equal to "content". Of those selected nodes, only keep those which are the second `div[@class = 'content']` element of their parent.

So, this expression would only select a result from the following document:

```
<root>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test1</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test2</div>
    <div class="other">other</div>
    <div class="content">MATCH</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test3</div>
 </div>
</root>
```

`//div[2][@class='content']` means:

> Select all elements called `div` from anywhere in the document, but only the ones that are the second child of their parent. Of those selected nodes, only keep those which have a `class` attribute whose value is equal to "content".

Only producing a match given a document like

```
<root>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test1</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="other">other</div>
    <div class="content">MATCH</div>
 </div>
 <div>
    <div class="content">test3</div>
 </div>
</root>
```